# How to use Span to make part of TextView Bold untill special character?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use a Span to make a part of textview bold untill special characters arrives like comma.
e.g;

**My Name is** , John

**Hello** , how are you

and if multiple commas arrive in a textview then it should use only first one ignore rest

Comment: Do you have a list of special characters? Or any character other than letters and numbers for the condition?

Comment: i have a comma .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically would be as next:

**Java**

```
void format(final TextView view) {

    final CharSequence text = view.getText();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        final int index = text.toString().indexOf(',');

        if (index > 0) {
            final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, index, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            view.setText(new SpannableString(sb));
        }
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun format(view: TextView) {

    val text = view.text

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        val index = text.indexOf(',')

        if (index > 0) {
            val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(text)
            sb.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, index, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            view.text = SpannableString(sb)
        }
    }
}
```

If on the other hand, is a resource string set to never change, then you can set bold tags directly into your strings resource xml file, with **<b> </b>**:

```
<string name="string_name"><b>Hello</b>, World</string>
```

Comment: what if text would contain multiple comma's

Comment: In the code you can see it uses 'indexOf' to find the first comma, this means it will make bold from index 0 to the index of the first found comma, and will ignore the rest after that index. So, wll be bold from the beginning until the first comma and ignore the rest. And if there are no commas in the text, then will not be bold at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer, let me show you ..how i do it...check my answer

Comment: please check my answer, but i will try with the ur one ,,,its easiest one

Answer (score 0):

```
var text:String? = property.name
    val spannable = SpannableString(text)
    val matcher: Matcher = Pattern.compile(",\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(text)
    while (matcher.find()){
        val city = matcher.group(1)
        val cityIndex: Int = text!!.indexOf(city) - 1
        val boldSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
        spannable.setSpan(boldSpan,0,cityIndex,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        holder.mTitleView?.text  =spannable
        return


    }
```